# cold weather meteorologists report index

Tags: c++

I'm new in c++ and trying to calculate "W = 33 - ( 10√v −v + 10.5) * (33 - t) / 23.1", but i don't know how to use sqrt() !!

here is my code :

```
/*  W=33−(10√v−v+10.5)(33−t)/23.1
Where 'V' is speed in (m/s)
Where 't' is temperature in degrees Celsius: t <= 10
Where 'W' is windchill index (in degrees Celsius)
*/

#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

double meteorologistReport(double V, double t, double W);

int main() {
  double V, t, W = 0;

  cout << "Please enter wind speed (m/sec) : ";
  cin >> V;

  cout << "Please enter temperature (degrees celsius <= 10 ) : ";
  cin >> t;


  if (t > 10) {
    cout << "You entered a value above 10! Please enter a value less then or equal to 10! " << endl;
  }

  else {
    W = 33 - (10√V - V + 10.5) * ( 33 - t ) / 23.1 );
    cout << "The WindChill index is : " << W << endl;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: What does " i don't know how to use sqrt()" mean?

Comment: The square root is like any other function:  `double result = sqrt(2);`.

Comment: In your case, you want `10 * sqrt(V)`.  The square root character is not a valid math operator in C++.

Comment: We really need a “Question does not reach minimum basic knowledge threshold” closure reason to guide Stack Overflow away from being used for rudimentary learning that is covered in textbooks.

Comment: *"i don't know how to use sqrt() !!"* -- that's quite a bit of code to cover this point. Did you consider simplifying? (You should have; the goal is a [mre].) The following would be enough to demonstrate your question, no? `int main() { double V = 2.1; double w = √V; }` or even `int main() { double w = √2.1; }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The square root character is not a valid math operator in C++.  You will have to use the `sqrt` function:
`10.0 * sqrt(V)`

*Note:  the square root is a floating point function, so all your values and variables should be `float` or `double`.*

Comment: The square root character is not a part of the ANSI character encoding and may terminal or input sources may not provide this character.  Thus the history behind calling it `sqrt`.  If you like all the math symbols, you may want to switch to ALGOL and get an ALGOL input device.